# How do you fetch all documents (including non-existent ancestor documents) in a Firebase collection?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pull all the documents in the collection 'users', but it only pulls 'fred' and 'lisa', and ignores all the italicized documents:

For this data:

[image]

Trying to get all documents:

[image]

Will yield:

```
info: length 2
info: fred  =>  { gender: 'male', contacts: [ '' ] }
      lisa  =>  { contacts: [ '' ] }
```

According to the Firebase documentation ([Firebase: Add and Manage Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console)):

> Warning: Even though non-existent ancestor documents appear in the console, they do not appear in queries and snapshots. You must create the document to include it in query results.

Note: The non-existent ancestor users seem to be auto-created when the user hits the sign-up button that triggers a `firebase.auth()` function (`fred` and `lisa` were created manually).

How would I print the `contacts` of each user if some of the users do not show up in my queries? Would I need to periodically run a script that manually re-adds all the users or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I think the warning from the documentation was quite clear, you just need to create these document manually when the users sign in. There's no need for re-add all users, you just need some extra code to write these documents during their sign-up process.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're trying to list all your registered users from Firebase auth, you can use the Firebase SDK function:

```
    function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
      admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
        .then(function(listUsersResult){
          listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
            console.log('user', userRecord.toJSON());
          })
          if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
            // list next batch of users
          }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Error listing users: ', error)
        });
    }

    listAllUsers();
```

via http://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned, these "documents" are displayed with an italic font in the Firebase console: this is because these documents are only present (in the console) as "container" of one or more sub-collection but they are not "genuine" documents.

As matter of fact, if you create a document directly under a `col1` collection with the full path `doc1/subCol1/subDoc1`, no intermediate documents will be created (i.e. no `doc1` document).

The Firebase console shows this kind of "container" (or "placeholder") in italics in order to "materialize" the hierarchy and allow you to navigate to the `subDoc1` document but `doc1` document doesn't exist in the Firestore database.

Let's take an example: Imagine a `doc1` document under the `col1` collection

```
col1/doc1/
```

and another one `subDoc1` under the `subCol1` (sub-)collection

```
col1/doc1/subCol1/subDoc1
```

Actually, from a technical perspective, they are not at all relating to each other. They just share a part of their path but nothing else. One side effect of this is that **if you delete a document, its sub-collection(s) still exist**.

So, if you want to be able to query for these parent documents, you will have to create them yourself, as jackz314 mentioned in the comments.