# How many documents a collection can be loaded in spark plan of firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase firestore. I'm not sure that how many documents can be created in a single collections as child. 
And i have another question, that is, i know there is a size limitation on each document. Is it applicable for mother document? I mean, suppose, i have a document1 in a collection and there is some collection inside this document and each collection has some document like d2,d3 etc. So is the size limit is for document1 or d2? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard limit on the number of documents you may store on the Spark plan.  A hard limit is placed on the total size of the database in your project.  The [documentation on pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) says you may have 1GB total.

Documents in subcollections are not limited in any way relative to any other document.  Each document is its own independent entity with its own size limit of 1 MB.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer, but suppose i have a mother document and there is 2 document inside mother documents collection where each child document size is 1 MB. So mother document is loaded as 2 mb size. Whats about it?

Comment: As I said in my answer: "Documents in subcollections are not limited in any way relative to any other document. Each document is its own independent entity with its own size limit of 1 MB."

Comment: Pardon me, can you please answer through my example to make me more clear about this issue?

Comment: Each document has a limit of 1MB.  It doesn't matter where the document is located.  Documents in subcollections don't count against the size of any parent documents.  I think you are maybe making this too complicated?

Comment: @midnightemotionsapp The example in this response may interest you, since it explains that there is actually no real notion of "mother document" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585594/how-do-you-fetch-all-documents-including-non-existent-ancestor-documents-in-a/55590692#55590692

Comment: yes you are right. I did little complicated too save read write usage. I have a app of notice. Its like Departmentnamecollection/coursenamedocument/yearcollection/monthdocument and whole notices are inside the monthdocument. I was hasitated that what is the size of coursenamedocument and if coursenamedocument size increases when i add new monthdocument.