# How to use wildcards in firebase security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to use a wildcard in my firebase security rules but it's not working like the online documentation describes.  [image]

I want to return the entire itineraryList collection but the security rules aren't working.

```
match /itinerary/{userId=**}/itineraryList/{doc} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId; 
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

What is the correct syntax here to give authenticated users access to the entire list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update following your comments:**

If you want to give read access to any authenticated user to all documents under the `itinerary` collection (including sub-collections), do as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /itinerary/{docId=**} {
          allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }   

      //possibly add another rule for write

  }
}
```

---

**Initial answer:**

This is because by doing `{userId=**}` you are using the "**recursive** wildcard syntax", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards. It will correspond to the "entire matching path segment".

You should do:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /itinerary/{userId}/itineraryList/{doc} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId; 
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }  
  }
}
```

You may also watch this official Firebase video about Firestore security rules, it explains this point, among others: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw

Comment: This only gives me the documents for the userId that matches the requesting user ID.  But I want the entire list for the users...not only if the userId field matches the requested userId.  This doesn't give me the entire list even if {userId} != userId

Comment: So what you want is that any authenticated user is able to read and write all documents under the `itinerary` collection (including sub-collections)? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes.  But only read permissions...I don't want to give them write.

Comment: This is my collection reference is the service providing a reference

      if (user) {
          this.allItineraries = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(`itinerary`);
        }

Comment: /itinerary/{userId=**} what this does is attempt to give me everything under /itinerary/userId...but there are no documents in userId.  I need the documents in /itinerary/userId/itineraryList/

Comment: I think the problem is actually in my collection reference:

          this.allItineraries = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(`itinerary`);
        }

I need the collection reference to reference the actual document but I'm not sure how to construct this with a wildcard in place of the username

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585594/how-do-you-fetch-all-documents-including-non-existent-ancestor-documents-in-a/55590692#55590692

Comment: PS: don't forget that Cloud Firestore Security Rules always begin with the following declaration: `service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // ...
  }
}`. I've updated my answer.