# Firestore billing for nested sub-collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When querying a deeply nested sub-collection, do you get charged for reading the documents at the top of the hierarchy or do you just get charged for the documents that belong to the sub-collection that is being read.

Comment: You may have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55590692/3371862. Docs of the top hierarchy have actually nothing to do with the ones of the sub-collection, they just share a part of their paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get charged for the documents that the server needs to read for you. If you only read documents from the subcollection, you will only get charged for those. There is no implicit read-from-top-level-collecton required for reading from a subcollection.

Comment: Hi Frank, does this work the other way round aswell. As in if i perform a read on a document which contains a subcollection, will firestore only charge me for the 1 parent document read?

Comment: If you only read the parent document, you will only be charged for the read of that parent document.